# En Ruby on Rails como insertar varios registros a la vez con ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Quiero hacer esto como si lo hiciera en `mysql`

```
INSERT INTO ratings
(`id`,`app_id`,`user_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`unique`,`valoracion`,`valoracions_id`) 
values (1,2,3,"2017-04-07","2017-04-07",12,4.8,1),
       (1,2,3,"2017-04-07","2017-04-07",12,4.8,1),
       (1,2,3,"2017-04-07","2017-04-07",12,4.8,1);
```

Comment: Puedes probrar algo así: `user_string = " ('a@ao.in','a'), ('b@ao.in','b')"
User.connection.insert("INSERT INTO users (email, name) VALUES"+user_string)`   Aquí hay mas soluciones http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803705/how-to-insert-multiple-records-into-database

Comment: creo que es una mala practica de igual forma gracias

Answer (score 2):

Se puede crear varios objetos con el médoto `create` pasandole un arreglo de hashes, en donde cada hash describe los atributos del objeto que se desea crear.

En la [apidock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) se encuentra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
# Create an Array of new objects
User.create([{ :first_name => 'Jamie' }, { :first_name => 'Jeremy' }])
```

Por lo tanto para tu caso debe ser algo así:

```
Rating.create([
{app_id: 1, unique: 12, valoracion: 4.8, valoracions_id: 1},
{app_id: 2, unique: 12, valoracion: 4.8, valoracions_id: 1},
{app_id: 3, unique: 12, valoracion: 4.8, valoracions_id: 1}
])
```

Comment: dale gracias pero si tuviese en el formulario varios campos `< input type="text" name="rating[valoracion]" >`  con el mismo name ya que los demás campos van a ser los mismos como haría?

Comment: Si ocupas varios inputs con el mismo atributo name solamente podrás obtener el valor del primero.

Comment: como haría para agregarlos todos?